# The maximum size of an antichain in a poset

Tags: combinatorics

Given $A$ as an n-element set and $X=p(A)$, I need to show that if $F$ is an antichain in the poset $(X,\subseteq)$ such that the maximum size of $F$'s elements is $n/2$ then $\mid F \mid \leq (_k^n)$ where $k \leq n/2$.

I guess that intuitively, we have to show that, in Hasse diagram, the mid-most level (the rank of which is $n/2$) is the longest antichain. My attempt is:
According to Dilworth's dual theorem, since "a" longest chain in $(X,\subseteq)$ is of size $n$, we can decompose the poset into $n$ antichains. Now since each chain and each antichain meet in at most one joint, and since there are $(_k^n)$ mid-level elements (so there are $(_k^n)$ chains) there could be $(_k^n)$ anti chains at max.

Am I correct? if not, any help would be appreciated.